# When does Sam lose his psychic powers?

Tags: supernatural

In the television series Supernatural, at what point of time and during which season did Sam lose his powers?

EDIT: I mean to ask whether it was around the time Sam was brought back from hell without his soul by Cass, that he completely lost all his powers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sam loses his powers whenever he stops drinking demon blood.  Bobby and Dean made him go through a detox in order to get all of the demon blood out of him.  It looks like this happened some time in season 4 after Dean came back.  However in at least one episode Sam intentially drank demon blood for one reason or another and ends up going through detox again.  At the end of season 5 we see him drinking gallons of demon blood to prepare him to host Lucifer so that they can capture him.

Comment: In the eigth season there is no mention of Sam's powers at all. When did that happen?

Comment: @user221287 most of this happens in seasons 4 and 5.

Answer (score -5):

end of 5.start of 6 ..when he becomes soulless sam.